# how do I clear google chrome console suggessions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to clear the console suggestion because I entered some data in it and dont want it to been seen by others.
Just want to know if there is way or do I just go to %appdata% and clear off things.

Comment: You mean console history, right? One that can be accessed using up/down arrows. Not the autocomplete feature (popup that appears when you start typing)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**[EDIT]** As of [Chrome 50](https://crbug.com/594342), you can use "Clear console history" from the console context menu.

[image: Clear console history - Chrome DevTools]

---

The situation seems to be a bit unlikely to happen (confident information in the devtools console?), but I've found the problem of clearing command history interesting. Especially, when it turned out that nothing from the `'Settings'->'Clear browsing data...'` clears it. Closing the tab or restarting the browser doesn't help either.

First, I've opened DevTools (**A**) in a separate window:

[image: DevTools - detaching window]

Then, knowing that DevTools are in fact a webapp, I've opened another DevTools window (**B**) inside already opened one (**A**) using [keyboard shortcut](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts#opening-devtools). Next, I've navigated to the "Resoures" tab, and in the "Local storage" section found a `consoleHistory` entry.

[image: DevTools - clearing command history]

After removing it (right-click and "Delete") and closing both DevTools windows (**A** and **B**) I found my console history empty.

Comment: This is interesting simply because I've learned that devtools is just a webapp which you can inspect

Answer (score 4):

I actually ran into this issue (needing to clear `consoleHistory`) when I maxed out its capacity. In this case clicking on `chrome-devtools://de...` in inspector would crash the window and trying to delete via `localStorage.clear()` or `localStorage.removeItem()` would timeout or be otherwise unsuccessful.

**At the end of it -- my fix was deleting the localStorage data files themselves.** On a mac, the instructions are:

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage
rm chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage
rm chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage-journal
```

A quick google search suggests on Windows it's `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`, but you may need to double check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and see if it helps. Open the console
[keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts#opening-devtools) and just right click anywhere bellow current typing line and select "clear console history".
[( Screenshot )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQxgs.png)