# Chrome dev tools console completely blank

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The problem is not that my `console.log` is not printed in the console. The problem is that the console is initially blank. I need to switch the tabs back and forth to get it working. Steps to reproduce:
1. Open Google chrome
2. Open some page
3. Open the console with Ctrl+Shift+I or F12

I even reinstall the browser (I kept the settings, because I can't afford to delete everything). Of course I removed all the extensions and disabled all the plugins. Still the same thing. Is there any application cache which I could delete to fix the problem.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

P.S.
The error which you see is actually from the current page. It is not from the console. Here is what I see when open dev tools inside dev tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'statusBarResized' of undefined inspector.js:2181
```

And all this happen after the latest big update of the browser.

Comment: Try clearning all settings of the devtools, by opening the devtools inside the devtools and running `localStorage.clear()` (or go to Resources -> Local Storage -> `devtools://devtools` -> Delete all items one by one)

Comment: Hey, that worked :) Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Make sure the frame underneath it hasn't been shrunk up to the bottom of the tab bar. I stumbled on this thread trying to figure out why I couldn't see anything in console and it turns out the lower frame had resized upward to obscure the console text after continual browser window resizing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your preferences have probably become corrupted. If you can reproduce the bug, please open a ticket at http://crbug.com/new.

Reset the preferences to resolve the issue. These are saved in localStorage on `chrome-devtools://devtools`, so you need to open the devtools of the devtools (step 1-2 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21149275/938089), and either:

- Run `localStorage.clear()` (switch to the Console tab or press Esc to open a drawer)
- ***OR*** Go to Resources, Local Storage and delete all items of the dev tools one by one.

Comment: I solved this by going to the Dev Tools preferences and restoring defaults.

Comment: only clearing the storage of the devtools of the devtools worked for me, not restoring defaults

Answer (score 8):

The suggestion of clearing localStorage either didn't work or only worked temporarily for me. As mentioned in some of the comments, the solution that worked for me was to:

1. Open developer tools
2. Open settings pane from top right (or F1)
3. Click the 'Restore defaults and reload' button

I should also mention that I'm using Google Chrome 53.0.2754.0 canary (64-bit).