# Chrome Dev Tools is blank

Tags: ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

I develop a ionic application, and I get a blank page in the Genymotion emulator. So I wanted to debug with chrome dev tools but I get a blank page when clicking on Inspect from chrome://inspect/#devices: index.html file:///android_asset/www/index.html

The Chrome dev tools console displays 2 errors:

```
inspector.js:4327 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
VM43:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExtensions' of undefined
```

I also cleared the localStorage and resets the default settings as mentioned in [Chrome dev tools console completely blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348759/chrome-dev-tools-console-completely-blank)

```
Chrome Version 49.0.2623.47 beta-m
WebView using Crosswalk 12 Chromium Version 41.0.2272.74
```

Comment: i had a similarly issues my   addEventListener  only works in a controller try using $ionicplatform.ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the Chrome version has to match somehow. I try with Chrome Portable 43, and it works.

Comment: I had this problem as well. Thank you for taking the time to post the answer to your own question.