# Chrome dev tools completely blank & unresponsive High Sierra

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For about a week, Chrome dev tools has been completely blank every time I try to use it on my Mac ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haezh.png)). I have reinstalled it but to no avail. Once I open dev tools, the specific tab seems to break - I have to open a new tab to be able to navigate, and none of the dev tools tabs & buttons work, so I cannot use any of the suggestions included here:

[Chrome dev tools console completely blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348759/chrome-dev-tools-console-completely-blank)

I am using High Sierra 10.13.2 & chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (64-bit)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Download [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) and see if the problem is fixed when you run the latest Chrome code. If it's fixed, then there was just some temporary regression that's causing Chrome to break.

If the issue is still there when you run Canary, [file a bug](https://crbug.com)!

Comment: thanks @KayceBasques. I followed your advice, but the issue remained on Canary. I have also filed a bug. Extremely frustrating!