# How to remove all recent console commands from Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools, input-history

Google Chrome v48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) for Mac OS seems to retain all console commands indefinitely. None of the following have any affect:

- clear()
- console.clear()
- Command-K
- turning off "preserve log" and "show all messages"
- Clear browsing data, from the beginning of time, all options check marked - removing all cookies
- quitting and restarting or shutting down and rebooting.
- Any combo of the above.
- Unable to locate a chrome_debug.log file anywhere on the system (i.e. logging is not check marked).
- Trashing Google Chrome and the associated library files then re-installing got rid of the console history, but the new version nonetheless holds all console subsequent console entries indefinitely.

Any insights? Any idea where this information gets stored?

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/21149275/1705006

Comment: Karmiphuc -- thanks for the reply.  I'd tried that before without success, but in looking more carefully at the instructions I got it to work. It's slightly understated on that page that you have to call the developer tools twice.  So pull up a browser window, Command-Shift-I (mac shortcut).  There is no option in that window for Local Storage > chrome-devtools:// but there's more... with the Developer Tools window undocked, do a SECOND Command-Shift-I, which pulls up yet another Developer Tools window.  Look under Local Storage > chrome-devtools://devtools > consoleHistory.  Thanks Karmiphuc

Comment: you're welcome. You can mark it as solved now.

Comment: Tried to 2 days & happy to do so now, but no green check mark available.  Perhaps you need to post your comment as an answer first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all recent console command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149156/how-to-remove-all-recent-console-command)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows 10. Just Simply go the console and right click then click on clear console
[image: Here is the screen shot of my browser]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Karmiphuc and the following link:
[How to remove all recent console command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149156/how-to-remove-all-recent-console)
which mostly answers the question.

It's slightly understated there that, on Mac OS at least, you have to call the developer tools **twice** consecutively.

So 1st pull up a browser window, and do Command-Shift-I (Mac shortcut).

Then, making sure the Developer Tools window is undocked, do a **second** Command-Shift-I which pulls up yet another Developer Tools window.

Now look under Local Storage > chrome-devtools://devtools > consoleHistory.