# Clear chrome devtools history

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I use the console a lot to enter and evaluate expressions. Often times i am wrong and fudged some expression names. After doing so, the chrome devtools console will autocomplete and suggest some of my mistypings.

Is there a way to clear console history suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all recent console command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149156/how-to-remove-all-recent-console-command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is stored in Local Storage in the context of DevTools itself, presumably to prevent accidental or malicious access/modifications from websites using the Web Storage API. You can follow the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21149275/1814840) to clear the history. It saves me having to repeat the details unnecessarily.