# How do I clear the history in my chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, console

How do I clear content/history in the Chrome console. Doing clear() doesn't erase the memory. command + r doesn't either. Once I start to type in something previously entered it starts to bring up that item again.

Comment: Go to History and then clear browsing data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149156/how-to-remove-all-recent-console-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all recent console command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149156/how-to-remove-all-recent-console-command)